# Using regex to validate JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I got a simple JSON that could benefit from some regex testing

```
{
    "Name": "Ingemar Stenmark",
    "personalNumber": "197304211770",
    "id": "069234f2-771c-415a-aa5a-3ca77c74f832"
}
```

It would be formatted like that exempt no line breaks (`{"Name": "Ingemar Stenmark", "personalNumber": "197304211770", "id": "069234f2-771c-415a-aa5a-3ca77c74f832"}`)

Is there any way it could be tested in js using regex?

Comment: What purpose does this validation serve? E.g. if you just generated it with `JSON.stringify()` then why validate it? Also, when exactly would it fail validation, and when wouid it succeed?

Comment: Regex is a good tool for so called "regular languages." JSON has a recursive grammar, so regex is not a great tool for that (or HTML or anything else in the recursive category)

Comment: You want to test the formatting of the values for each "persons" info?

Comment: @PeterB The JSON is being shipped to another system and could use some validation when arriving.

Comment: @Jacob I know but this is a test if the JSON follows this format or not. If not, then it's not a match

Comment: @MarioPerez Yea, the values.

Comment: If you only want to test the values, you could iterate through the values and use regexes to test each of them. As opposed to stringifying the whole object and testing with one big regex, which makes things more complicated.

Comment: @xdhmoore Well, that assumes that I'm the one constructing the JSON.

Comment: If you aren't creating the JSON, you could still deserialize it first as a baseline test. And then test the values with regexes. But I guess it depends on what you want to test. Are you wanting to make sure the JSON is valid, testing the ability of the service to create valid JSON? Or test that the data fields are valid? Or maybe you want to make sure the code that uses the data handles invalid JSON/fields correctly?

Answer (score 1):

It would need to be a string for you to run a regex test on it.

But once it's a string you can create a regex using the js global RegExp https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp and use the RegExp `test` method:

```js
const json = {
    "Name": "Ingemar Stenmark",
    "personalNumber": "197304211770",
    "id": "069234f2-771c-415a-aa5a-3ca77c74f832"
};

const jsonStr = JSON.stringify(json);
const regex = RegExp(<regex here>);

console.log(regex.test(jsonStr));
```